# Can't override cookbook attributes with Chef environment

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I'm trying to override default cookbook attributes (in this case,  attributes for nginx). In my default cookbook attributes I have something like this:

```
default[:my_nginx_cookbook][:site_name] = 'defaultnginx.site.com'

default[:my_nginx_cookbook][:sites] = {
"default.site.com" => {
default_value1: 'stuff'
default_value2: 'yada yada'
},
"default2.site.com" => {
default_value3: 'even more stuff'
default_value4: 'blah blah'
  }
}
```

I want to override these attributes in the environment where I'm deploying the cookbook (I'll call the environment FOO). In my FOO environment file, I have the following:

```
override_attributes[:my_nginx_cookbook] = {
site_name: 'myrealnginx.site.com'
}

override_attributes[:my_nginx_cookbook][:sites] = {
'myreal.site.com' => {
 real_value1: 'real stuff'
 real_value2: 'real yada'
 },
"myreal2.site.com" => {
real_value3: 'more real stuff'
real_value4: 'real blah'
  }
}
```

However, when I run chef client on the nginx node, it only creates the default sites. I've had no problem overriding default attributes in other environments. Am I not overriding the defaults correctly in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you have in the environments file or are you paraphrasing and misrepresented the code?

Comment: @coderanger Thanks for your response. Other than giving the actual attributes and data, that is what's in my environment file. I have a have a hunch that the problem is syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Chef environment file, you would generally set attribute data like this:

```
override_attributes({
  my_nginx_cookbook: {
    site_name: 'myrealnginx.site.com',
    sites: {
      'myreal.site.com' => {
        real_value1: 'real stuff'
        real_value2: 'real yada'
      },
      'myreal2.site.com' => {
        real_value3: 'more real stuff'
        real_value4: 'real blah'
      },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately even with this syntax the default sites are created, but not the sites specified in environment file.

Comment: Check with `knife` command to make sure the file is uploading and that the node is in the right org. If the converge is succeeding you should be able to check the attribute data via `knife node show -l -Fj`.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as it is technically the correct answer to the question that was asked.